# MySQL Query for selecting next row data within a single ID

Tags: mysql

The data columns are ID, Data, and Actual Create Date

Here is sample data.

```
ID  Data        Actual Create Date
111 Open        2018-02-28
111 Comment     2018-02-28
111 Resolved    2018-03-01
222 Open        2018-03-02
222 Comment     2018-03-03
222 Resolved    2018-03-05
```

What I need to do is, within a single ID (EG. 111), I need to create a column called end date that takes the actual create date of the next row and makes it the end date for the previous entry unless the entry is Resolved and then the end date is the create date.  so that the data looks like the following

```
ID  Data        Actual Create Date      End Date
111 Open        2018-02-28              2018-02-28
111 Comment     2018-02-28              2018-03-01
111 Resolved    2018-03-01              2018-03-01
222 Open        2018-03-02              2018-03-03
222 Comment     2018-03-03              2018-03-05
222 Resolved    2018-03-05              2018-03-05
```

apparently I need to provide the queries I have run so far according to strawberry

```
SELECT a.IssueId AS ID, b.ShortId, a.Title AS Issue_Description, a.Request_Type, a.Site, b.Path, b.`Data`, b.`Actual Create Date`
FROM SIM_FE a
LEFT JOIN SIM_FE_Audit_Data b ON b.IssueId = a.IssueId
WHERE b.`Data` IN ('Open','Comment','Audit','Feasibility','Deep Dive','Scoping','Pending Others','Awaiting Requester Info','Resolved')
AND a.Request_Type LIKE '%Capacity:%'
```

that gets me all the data I need.  There is no unique key though because the data is an audit trail of things that happened.  The ID is unique to a project, but because multiple things show up in `Data` for each project (ID column) you get multiple IDs.  Short ID, Issue Description, Request_Type, Site and Path are all just for the data visualization on the other side; they could be left out in terms of the query function as they are likewise not unique.

The function of this query is to essentially create the stop date for each of the steps in a process.  Currently there is only a start date (Actual Create Date) for each step.  Thus, the ability to assign the "next step's" actual create date to the previous step as an ending date.  I have tried tweaking the proposed answer in every way I can think of, but it doesn't work as intended.  I go from 255 rows with the base query to over 143K.

Here is my next try:

```
SELECT a.IssueId AS ID, a.Title AS Issue_Description, a.Request_Type, a.Site, b.`Data`, b.`Actual Create Date`, b.`End Date`, b.rank
FROM SIM_FE a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        IssueId, 
        `Data`, 
        `Actual Create Date`, 
        @rank:=CASE WHEN @id <> IssueId THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rank,
        @id:=IssueId AS IssueId1,
        `End Date`
    FROM
        (SELECT @rank:=-1) r,
        (SELECT @id:= -1) i,
        (SELECT *
         FROM SIM_FE_Audit_Data
         WHERE `Data` IN ('Open','Comment','Audit','Feasibility','Deep Dive','Scoping','Pending Others','Awaiting Requester Info','Resolved')
         ORDER BY IssueId, `Actual Create Date`
        ) s
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            IssueId AS ID2,
            `Actual Create Date` As `End Date`
        FROM
            SIM_FE_Audit_Data
    ) t ON t.ID2 = s.IssueId -1
) b ON b.IssueId = a.IssueId
WHERE Request_Type LIKE '%Capacity:%'
```

This one is strange, but basically End dates are duplicated repeatedly.  Causes 255 rows to become 39814 rows.  So, the join has to be wrong.

Hopefully I did this SQLFiddle right

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/788b7/1

Comment: What other `Data` values are possible? Is it always in that order? Can there be multiple `Open` and `Comment` values for same `ID`?

Comment: The following are possible 'Open','Comment','Audit','Feasibility','Deep Dive','Scoping','Pending Others','Awaiting Requester Info','Resolved' In theory they should only happen once, but you can have multiple of at least Comment; I could and probably should exclude comment now that you mention that

Comment: So in that case, which order to set them in if the date is the same? Considering your example, it's seems obvious but there is no logic for you to pick `End Date` for `Open` to be the one from `Comment`. It could have been the other way around as well.

Comment: The only order that I can use to determine that is to use the actual create date (which is actually a datetime and not only a date, but it was easier to post as a date) as a marker and put them in order by that create date.  so Open is always first and Resolved is always last. Those are the only hard points I have.  From the first hard point I can only use the next actual create date for that ID to put it in the right order.  The hope is that the people are actually following a process, but I can't count on that.

Comment: Go on. Try something. And if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can do:

Calculate the rank to get the order of all the rows for each `ID`.

```
SELECT t.id, t.data, t.create_date,
   @rank:=CASE WHEN @id <> id THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rn,
   @id:=id AS idl
FROM
  (SELECT @rank:= -1) r,
  (SELECT @id:= -1) i,
  (SELECT *
   FROM mytable
   ORDER BY id, create_date
  ) t
```

Then join this table by itself using unique columns and use t1.id = t2.id + 1. That will give you matching rows for all except the last one where you can use a `CASE` statement to get the original date.

Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

After working with SQLFiddle, here is the updated query which should give results similar to the one in the question.

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.data, r1.create_date, r2.create_date END_DATE
FROM (SELECT t.id, t.data, t.create_date,
   @rank:=CASE WHEN @id <> id THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rank,
   @id:=id AS idl
FROM
  (SELECT @rank:= -1) r,
  (SELECT @id:= -1) i,
  (SELECT *
   FROM Table1
   ORDER BY id, create_date
  ) t) r1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t.id, t.data, t.create_date,
   @rank:=CASE WHEN @id <> id THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rank,
   @id:=id AS idl
FROM
  (SELECT @rank:= -1) r,
  (SELECT @id:= -1) i,
  (SELECT *
   FROM Table1
   ORDER BY id, create_date
  ) t) r2 ON r1.rank = r2.rank - 1 AND r1.id = r2.id
```

Instead of repeating the same subquery for `r1` and `r2`, you can use `WITH` and join the table with itself twice. For some reason, SQLfiddle didn't like it so I did it this way.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac311/7

Comment: I am still playing with this, but so far I have gone from about 10000 rows to over 140K rows; so there is some really big error I have in here

Comment: You are probably missing a key for your joins. Can you post what you have?

Comment: Yea, there is no unique key in these tables.  I think there would have to be a unique key to do this

Comment: Yes! That might help. :)

Comment: The rank feature?

Comment: @Strawberry changed wording. Feel free to edit if it still doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Nope, still not sounding right. You happened to choose the word RANK, but TAXI would work just as well, or indeed any string you cared to consider.

Comment: The ranking part of this is the only way to get a unique key for each ID; at least that is what I am thinking after looking at this hard.  so it essentially creates the key I would need in order to be able to get the next row value.

Comment: Unless you get a rank of all the rows, it will not be unique. The way I have it in the query is so that it will rank each group starting from 1 which will cause you to have a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle so we can take a look and help?

Comment: maybe; let me see if I can sanitize the data enough.

Comment: @Shenanigator Edited the answer.